# A question on supersymmetry variation of the Wilson loop in $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, supersymmetry, yang-mills, wilson-loop

The Wilson loop in $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM is
$$W=\frac{1}{N}tr P \exp \int ds (i A_\mu(x) \dot{x}^\mu+\Phi_i(x)\theta^i|\dot{x}|).\tag{2.3}$$

In order to check whether this operator is supersymmetric I will use a variation.
We know that the supersymmetry transformations of the bosonic fields are
$$\delta_\epsilon A^\mu=\bar{\Psi}\Gamma^\mu \epsilon\tag{2.2a}$$
$$\delta_\epsilon\Phi^i=\bar{\Psi}\Gamma^i \epsilon\tag{2.2b}$$

The supersymmetry variation of the Wilson loop is
$$\delta_\epsilon W=\frac{1}{N}tr P  \int ds\bar{\Psi}(i \Gamma_\mu \dot{x}^\mu+\Gamma_i\theta^i|\dot{x}|)\epsilon  \exp \int ds' (i A_\mu(x) \dot{x}^\mu+\Phi_i(x)\theta^i|\dot{x}|).\tag{2.4}$$
The references I have checked (e.g. [arXiv:hep-th/0205160](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0205160)) say that vanishing of the supersymmetry
variation of the Wilson loop require
$$(i \Gamma_\mu \dot{x}^\mu+\Gamma_i\theta^i|\dot{x}|)\epsilon=0.\tag{2.5}$$

Why not

$$\bar{\Psi}(i \Gamma_\mu \dot{x}^\mu+\Gamma_i\theta^i|\dot{x}|)\epsilon=0\tag{A}$$
or
$$i \Gamma_\mu \dot{x}^\mu+\Gamma_i\theta^i|\dot{x}|=0~?\tag{B}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly, eq. (2.5) is preferred over eq. (A) because it only depend on intrinsic Wilson loop data and not the fermion $\bar{\Psi}$. Eq. (B) is too strong and does not have non-trivial solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry, how can we be sure that there are no solutions for (B) ?

Comment: Because the Gamma matrices are lin. indep.